# Contar pixels cinzentos e pretos dum desenho em c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Tenho um desenho pintado com canetas de feltro e digitalizado,
apenas sete cores estão presentes: verde, azul, preto, cinzento, violeta, laranja e vermelho
necessito de saber a percentagem de cor utilizada.

Não consigo distinguir os píxeis cinzentos dos pretos, podem ajudar ?

**Tenho a imagem de entrada -> `srcimage`**

```
Mat srcimage, hsvimage, HSV_threshold, thres_dst;
srcimage = imread("teste.jpg", IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_4);

cvtColor(srcimage , hsvimage, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
Mat HSV = hsvimage.clone();
int low_H = 0, low_S = 0, low_V = 0;
int high_H = 0, high_S = 0, high_V = 0;


low_H = 75, low_S = 6, low_V = 200;
high_H = 120, high_S = 48, high_V = 211;
inRange(HSV, Scalar(low_H, low_S, low_V), Scalar(high_H, high_S, high_V), HSV_threshold);

Mat binfinal, binfinalsrc;
bitwise_and(HSV, HSV, binfinal, HSV_threshold);
bitwise_and(srcimagetemp, srcimagetemp, binfinalsrc, HSV_threshold);
```

Comment: de RGB(0,0,0) preto até RGB(245,245,245) cinzento. Portanto você precisa de uma função que leia os componentes RGB de cada cor.

Comment: sugeres a utilização da imagem em rgb ? o problema e que a variação é enorme e todosos intervalos são validos

Comment: o objectivo e contabilizar todas as cores incluindo o preto e cinzento só que têm valores na mesma gama, grata

Comment: por exemplo H=101 S=10 V= 211 satisfaz ambas as cores